# Javascript Non UTF-8 Character Searching for Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, utf-8, google-chrome-extension, turkish

Edit:

I am creating a Chrome Extension and the files must be UTF-8 encoded.
I use JQuery to get contents from page, and check that if that contains specific strings that contains Ö, ı and İ. However, because the Chrome forces files must be encoded UTF-8; I cannot perform a search of "İ, ı, Ö".

```
var p = txt.indexOf("İ");
```

Does not work as I need because I cannot save the files with İ, Ö or ı.

Comment: UTF-8 can represent pretty much any character, as long as you have a Unicode-aware text editor. Do you mean that the files must be saved as ASCII?

Comment: By the way, I highly recommend reading this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Isn't the bug that Javascript doesn't support Unicode? You should be able to write what you have written there without any trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript string literals include a [syntax for expressing special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Unicode_Escape_Sequences).

For instance, 'Ö' and '\u00D6' are identical strings in JavaScript.

To find the unicode literal for a specific character, you can do this:

```
'Ö'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); // yields "d6"; the code is "\u00D6"
```

Therefore, to search for a Ö in a string, you could do:

```
var toSearch = "abc Ö def";
if (toSearch.indexOf('\u00D6') > -1) {
    // found!
}
```

If you need further help, try posting a code sample.

Comment: Thats the quickest solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: What is a special character?  Any code point should stand for itself. You shouldn't need all those lame escapes. Just edit in UTF-8 and be done.

Answer (score 2):

```
encodeURIComponent(your string)
```

encode it when you save the file, and encode the string before you search

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: Thanks, both works for me but I will go with \u... instead :)